# How to work Phoenix Framework with Mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I am trying to use phoenix framework with mongodb as database so i run the following command to get started

```
mix phoenix.new helloworld --database mongodb
```

My `mix.exs` file looks like this:

```
defp deps do
  [{:phoenix, "~> 1.2.1"},
   {:phoenix_pubsub, "~> 1.0"},
   {:phoenix_ecto, "~> 3.0"},
   {:mongodb_ecto, ">= 0.0.0"},
   {:phoenix_html, "~> 2.6"},
   {:phoenix_live_reload, "~> 1.0", only: :dev},
   {:gettext, "~> 0.11"},
   {:cowboy, "~> 1.0"}]
end
```

but when I run `mix deps.get`, I get the following error:

```
Failed to use "ecto" (versions 2.0.0, 2.0.1, 2.0.2, 2.0.3, 2.0.4, 2.0.5, 2.0.6, 2.1.0, 2.1.1, 2.1.2, 2.1.3, 2.1.4) because
  mongodb_ecto (versions 0.1.0 to 0.1.2) requires ~> 1.0
  phoenix_ecto (version 3.0.1) requires ~> 2.0


Failed to use "ecto" (versions 2.0.0-beta.0 to 2.0.6) because
  mongodb_ecto (versions 0.1.0 to 0.1.2) requires ~> 1.0
  phoenix_ecto (version 3.0.0) requires ~> 2.0.0-rc


Failed to use "ecto" (version 2.0.6) because
  mongodb_ecto (versions 0.1.3 to 0.1.5) requires ~> 1.0.0
  phoenix_ecto (version 3.0.0) requires ~> 2.0.0-rc


Failed to use "ecto" (versions 2.1.0 to 2.1.4) because
  mongodb_ecto (versions 0.1.0 to 0.1.2) requires ~> 1.0
  phoenix_ecto (versions 3.1.0 to 3.2.3) requires ~> 2.1


Failed to use "ecto" (version 2.1.4) because
  mongodb_ecto (versions 0.1.3 to 0.1.5) requires ~> 1.0.0
  phoenix_ecto (version 3.0.1) requires ~> 2.0


Failed to use "ecto" (version 2.1.4) because
  mongodb_ecto (versions 0.1.3 to 0.1.5) requires ~> 1.0.0
  phoenix_ecto (versions 3.1.0 to 3.2.3) requires ~> 2.1

** (Mix) Hex dependency resolution failed, relax the version requirements of your dependencies or unlock them (by using mix deps.update or mix deps.unlock). If you are unable to resolve the conflicts you can try overriding with {:dependency, "~> 1.0", override: true}
```

How do I get started?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem here is that `mongodb_ecto` hasn't been updated in quite a while and hence doesn't support the newer versions of `Ecto` (v2.0 and above) which is what Phoenix is currently using. This causes `mix deps.get` to fail since it cannot resolve the dependencies.

One solution here is to directly use the [**MongoDB driver for Elixir**](https://github.com/ericmj/mongodb) instead of `mongodb_ecto` and configure it to work with `Ecto` in your Phoenix application. Here is a blog post that explains how you can do that:

> [**Phoenix with Ecto and MongoDB**](https://tomjoro.github.io/2017-02-09-ecto3-mongodb-phoenix/)

---

There's also another library that offers `MongoDB` support for `Ecto 2`, but it's still listed as `beta` on the project's github repository. You can check for yourself if it meets your usage criteria:

> [**eyrmedical/mongo_ecto**](https://github.com/eyrmedical/mongo_ecto)

Comment: what are the cons if i downgrade Ecto below 2.0?

Comment: You'll lose tons of new features and there's a good chance the app might not work correctly with the latest versions of other libraries that work with Ecto. See [Ecto's Changelog](https://github.com/elixir-ecto/ecto/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md).